# Where is my custom form

Tags: forms, formbuilder, access

I just created a from (through Form Builder) composed of custom data fields. Essentially this form is used to collect information about potential members that we are recruiting.

I have two questions.

First, I want to give it a try by entering some test data. Unfortunately, the form does not appear in any menu choice on CiviCRM. My question is how do I navigate to the newly created form to enter data?

Second, I want to give access to our recruiters to enter the data from a mobile phone. How do I set this up?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When composing your form there are some settings for this on the left side of the screen:

[image: Form Builder]

You'll want to add a **Page Route** so the form has a url. You can optionally add it to the menubar by checking **Add to Navigation Menu**.

To allow others to use the form, set the **Permission** appropriately so they have access, and then email or text them a link to the form.

Comment: Thanks - That worked.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept this answer

Comment: It should be marked as accepted now. Sorry for the delay.